# How to develop Horizontal scrolling calendar in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker, custom-renderer

I would like to develop my calendar view as in image. Is it possible with customizing datepicker?

[image: Horizontal Scrollable Calendar]

Comment: I think it is impossible with datepicker to do that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, Any plugins that are of free? I have tried with SyncFusion which is not free.

Comment: There are some ways in java to custom a calendar view ,such as https://www.telerik.com/forums/customization-of-android-calendar-monthview .However , xamarin need to custom `BoxView` to realize it.This need to translate java code to C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try some code like it

```
<ScrollView Orientation = "Horizontal">
  <ListView x:Name="datePicker"  ItemSelected="OnSelection" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Orientation = "Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center Padding="5,0,5,0">
            <Label Text="{Binding Date}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding month}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding week}" />
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

You can use th item selection to change the color and inotifypropertychanged to set new values for your grid vector.

Regards

Guilherme Marques